# What if the benefit of using a final instance in the classic singleton pattern (if any)?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, final

In the below snippet, `Singleton1#INSTANCE` is not `final`, while `Singleton2#INSTANCE` is:

```java
public class Singleton1 {

    private static Singleton1 INSTANCE = new Singleton1();

    private Singleton1() {}

    public static Singleton1 getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}

public class Singleton2 {

    private static final Singleton2 INSTANCE = new Singleton2();

    private Singleton2() {

    public static Singleton2 getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

What is the benefit of `Singleton2` over `Singleton1` (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none, Java wise. [Class initialization happens atomically, within locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2). No thread will be able to see `Singleton1#INSTANCE` partially created.

At this point, use `final` to clarify (to developers) that this field should not change.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that the answer is none for *performance*. It could prevent a bug if someone were to try and modify the reference at some point during the maintenance cycle.

Answer (score 2):

final is basically used for two purposes in java -

1) For immutability - If a field is final, then it can only be initialized only once. So, if INSTANCE  is not final then you can reinitialize creating one more object but this can only be done as constructor is private. So, basically final can avoid any other bugs which can be introduced at later stage as mentioned by Elliott.

2) To ensure that object is properly constructed before publishing (it is in context of multithreading) but since we are instantiating the INSTANCE on class loading (eager loading). It will not cause any issues. It will be created long before it will be used.